# css - center img+text with img left of text

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve this effect

[image: img]

Basically, I want an image and text both centered with the image to the left and text to the right. Both image and text are part of a bigger div that makes up its own row. It doesn't matter if the img or text is part of its own div as long as this effect is achieved.

It would be best to have this done without using flex, which I think is a common way to work around any trouble with spacing and position. However, I've read negative things about this technique so i rather just play it safe and not use it.

Help would be awesome, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward if you use display flex. 
You can then set the justify-content property to center.

```css
.parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

/* The following is optional, to add space between image and text */

.parent div {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><img src=" http://fillmurray.com/200/200"/></div>
  <div><p>Text for fun!!</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem. I wanted to achieve the center alignment of image and text and solved it using the technique that i used in this fiddle. Check this fiddle

```
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px;    display: flex;">
 <div style="color:white;overflow:hidden;width: 50%;height: 100px;">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="     margin-right: 10px;    float: right;   width: 75%;">

</div> 
<div style="color:white;/* padding:20px; */width: 50%;height: 100px;">
<h2 style="    margin-left: 10px;">This is text</h2>
</div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjxse6L/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use displa:flex then use can try this

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.section{
  float:left;
  margin:0 10px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <img src=" http://fillmurray.com/200/200" class="section"/>
    <div class="section"><p>Text for fun!!</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" style="border: 2px solid; text-align: center;">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>Parent Div</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 2px solid; margin: 14px;">
    <h3>Div of image</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 2px solid; margin: 14px;">
    <h3>Div of text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, see if you understand it or if you have any questions. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKppYd

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="images"><img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
  <div class="text">some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably.some text and stuff goes here probably. </div>
</div>



.container {
  text-align:center;

}
.top {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.images {
display:inline-block;
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width:350px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: an issue i seem to be having when using this code is that i want my top and bottom padding to be 0 but when i set this, the top padding will not go away, do u by anychance know how to fix